# Express Trees: Rewrite query predicates to use joins

Tags: c#, linq, expression-trees

I want to intercept a query to a database sent via Entity Framework and convert from something like

```
SELECT * FROM EntityA where (EntityA.Title Like "foo" 
OR EntityA.Description Like "foo") and EntityA.Prop1 in (1,2,3)
```

to

```
SELECT * FROM EntityA INNER JOIN EntityB on EntityA.ID = EntityB.ID 
WHERE (EntityB.Title Like "foo" or EntityB.Description Like "foo") and 
EntityA.Prop1 in (1,2,3)
```

I am using ExpressionTrees to pass in the predicates and using `ExpressionVisitor` I can

```
override Expression VisitBinary(BinaryExpression b)
```

to access the `Or` node.

I have a working implementation whereby I issue two separate calls to the db, one to get the ids of EntityA that meet the criteria title search criteria and 
another that combines that expression with the other predicates targeting properties on EntityA.

I would prefer to simply issue a single call with a rewritten query that leverages a `JOIN` but it's not clear how to rewrite the `Or` to create a join to an Entity type that was not a part of the original expression.

**Updated:** Typos in original post - Its the expression that has the wrong type for subsequent use.

```
// This doesn't work as it creates an Expression of the wrong type
Expression<Func<IEnumerable<EntityA>, IEnumerable<EntityB>, IEnumerable<EntityA>>> expa = 
(mvs, fts) => mvs.Join(fts, mv=> mv.ID, f => f.ID, (mv1, fts1) => new { FTS=fts1, MV=mv1})
.Where(fts1 => fts1.FTS.Title.Contains("foo") && fts1.FTS.Description.Contains("foo")).Select(a => a.MV);
```

Comment: I think you cannot replace only OR with join (you will have to modify more than just OR), but you can change it to something like `ctx.EntitiesB.Where(r => r.ID == entityA.ID).Any(r => r.Title.Contains(...) || r.Description.Contains(...)`, which probably still be converted to sql join.

Comment: In your "doesn't work" example you don't seem to be grabbing the `EntityA` off the anonymous type at the end. Are you perhaps missing a `.Select(a => a.FTS)`? Also you have `&&` but say `Or`.

Comment: @IanMercer Ah, sorry, typos in post, it's the expression that's of the wrong type for subsequent use. The compiler want seems to want a `Func<EntityA, bool>` to replace the (Or) part of of the query. So basically I have an `&&` - the right side of which i want to retain, but replacing the left side  which is an (Or) - with a join to an EntityB not in the original expression.